# Adding omniauth to devise routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am following this guide https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview
to configure devise with omniauth facebook sign up, now I am at the step where I need to add the omniauth_callbacks route to the devise routes, i have already customized a devise controller like this :

```
devise_for :users, controllers:{
    registrations: "users/registrations"
  }
```

So I added the omniauth route like this

```
devise_for :users, controllers:{
    registrations: "users/registrations"
    :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"
  }
```

But now the server is not starting because of a syntax error, I am pretty sure I need a block in the routes. 
Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a missing comma

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: "users/registrations",
    omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"
}
```